# Get versions of packages currently built from BitBake

Tags: build, yocto, bitbake

I have a Yocto Poky build with a handful of standard layers and then some layers for our software. As that software is being developed, the versions are, automatically, bumped, so soon the `build/tmp/deploy/tar` contains many versions of some of the packages; say `app-8.9.2-r0.tar.gz`, `app-8.9.8-r0.tar.gz`, `app-8.9.13-r0.tar.gz` and `app-8.10.1-r0.tar.gz`.

And I would like to pick out all those that are part of the current build. Which may not be the highest numbered when e.g. the build server builds a branch with newer version and then a build of master that doesn't have that version yet.

Now the tricky part is that I need *package* versions, not *recipe* versions, for two reasons:

- Even if the packages always used the recipe versions, for many packages I still wouldn't immediately know which recipe they are built by.
- But mainly the package versions are *not* the same as the recipe versions. These recipes calculate the versions, and bitbake is trying to use `${PV}` too early, so they actually set `PV = "0.0.1"` and then set `PKGV` to the calculated version.

But `bitbake -g` does not give any versions and `bitbake -s` only gives the recipe versions (`PV`) and I need the package versions (`PKGV`). Is there somewhere else or some other way to get the versions?

Comment: I would note that I don't think we are using it the way it was intended, but it's been used like this for years and the team is fragmented to subteams supporting different customers, so it's not really possible to change now.

Comment: I'm not sure, but you could check your manifest file (https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-IMAGE_MANIFEST)

Comment: I'm pretty sure buildhistory could help you with that though it probably will only give you packages installed in the image. c.f. http://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev-manual/dev-manual-common-tasks.html#maintaining-build-output-quality

Comment: It actually appears the pkgdata is always there and contains the information. Getting just the versions from there should be simple, too. The dependency information looks a bit harder to process, but should be doable as well. I don't know whether there is a library or command to help with it though.